# Delete data in realtime firebase database: messages of a certain user and the user itself

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We want to delete all the messages of a certain user and the user at a certain event. We know how to delete a user but have no clue how to delete his messages. The following picture is showing our database:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atofr.png)

The messages should be deleted below the removal of the user
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bycS7.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger a firebase function when deleting a user.

In firebase you could get a user ID and search trought your database.

This is typically a backend funcion.

Firebase provide an [extention](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/delete-user-data) for this purpose